# Loading image not working on MVC due to required fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I'm developing a website using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have the following issue. I'm trying to display the loading image when the server is processing. It actually works fine when I haven't made any mistakes when filling the form. BUT, when I miss a required field for example, the loading image pops up and it doesn't go away and the validation of the field is made.
I've tried to use jQuery to do something like this

```
    $(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
    alert(form.valid());
    if (form.valid()) {
        $("#divLoading").show();
        $.post({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divLoading").hide();
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Not valid.");
    }
    //}
});
```

});

So, when I ask if the form is valid it returns true, in spite of leaving a required field blank.

My model is the following:

```
    public class MotivoDTO
    {
        public MotivoDTO()
        {
        }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a Motive.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Descripcion")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    }
```

Thank you! (...and sorry for my English)

Comment: Where div loading html and css for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your .ajax() call to make use of the different events available to you inside of the ajax() function.

```
$(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
    alert(form.valid());
    if (form.valid()) {

        $.post({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            //do this before you start the POST method
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#divLoading").show();
            },
            //do this regardless if it was successful or not
            complete: function (data) {
                $("#divLoading").hide();
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Not valid.");
    }
 }
```

Comment: That was it!  I've removed the jQuery validation a just did what you told and it works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate the form first:

```
form.validate();
if (form.valid()) {
```

I supose that form is the jquery object of the form you want to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Enable unobtrusive validation in your application. What is happening now is that you are validating on the server which is fine. But in doing so you are enabling the progress control but if there is an validation error you are never turning it off. Unobtrusive validation will allow your validation to take place on the client. You can if you want place the divLoading show outside your if statement and add a hide command in your else statement.

[Unobstrusive Validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

It may also be a good idea to make sure that the loading div is hidden regardless of the result of your post method. [jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

For example:

```
$.post({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divLoading").hide();
        }
    }).always(function() { $("#divLoading").hide(); });
```

Comment: Hi mike, welcome at Stackoverflow. I took the freedom to edit your post somewhat, if you add 4 spaces before some code, it will automatically format it for you. It looks better that way. Thanks for your answer. Cheers!